# Averagex not producing the correct total

Tags: dax, average, powerbi-desktop

I have created a DAX measure which gets the previous period value which is correct on a row by row basis, however because the context i'm using it in is non-additive it causes the grand total to be incorrect.

The solution would be to create another DAX measure which creates a summary table to actually look at the exact individual values and get the average of those numbers but the total is still yielding an incorrect result.

```
testMeasure = 
VAR _summary = 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Calendar', 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence]),
        "bays",
        [AvgBaysPreviousYear]
    )
RETURN
AVERAGEX(_summary, [bays])
```

[image]

The average should show as `7,714.24`

PBI file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQslMEqdntvcH4Th6kESm8EaIYJN-QwM/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix?

Comment: i'll need to sanitise the data, but I can share to your email

Comment: Upload to a sharing site and then update your question with the link.

Comment: i've added the pbix file link

Comment: Your _summary table returns just one row with a single value for AvgBaysPreviousYear of 3857.12. It is hard to know what you're trying to do from your model. You should avoid many to many relationships at all costs as they cause unexpected issues.

Comment: the many to many table is only because theres one value that has duplicates, its an error on the actual back end data source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256531/discussion-between-jcoke-and-davide-bacci).

Comment: Sorry, I have to go out. Maybe Sam will understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

```
totalAverageBays = 
    AVERAGEX (
        SUMMARIZE('Campaign Overview', 'Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence], "bays", [totalAverageBaysFinalVersion])
        ,[bays]
    )

AvgBaysPreviousYear = 
IF (
    ISFILTERED('Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence]) || ISFILTERED('Calendar'[Calendar Financial Year]),
    CALCULATE ( 
        [totalAverageBays],
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Calendar Date])
    )
)
```

You have the above two measures, where `totalAverageBays` is doing a weekly average based on week commencing, but then `AvgBaysPreviousYear` is asking `totalAverageBays` to do the same for the same **dates** as last year. And last year in the same date range, it happens to overlap **two** weeks. And in one of those weeks it was 0 so you're getting the average of `0` and `7,714.24`.

**Solution**
What you need to do is get the same week number as last year and get the calculation on that.

Luckily, your `Calendar` table has `Year & Week` and `YOY Year & Week` columns which we can leverage.

First, let's clean up `totalAverageBays` (doing the same thing):

```
totalAverageBays = 
  AVERAGEX (
    DISTINCT('Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence],
    [totalAverageBaysFinalVersion]
  )
```

Now let's tackle the YoY for the same week numbers.

```
AvgBaysPreviousYear = 
  var lastYearWeeks = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('Calendar'[YOY Year & Week]))
  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      [totalAverageBays],
      REMOVEFILTERS('Calendar'),
      'Calendar'[Year & Week] IN lastYearWeeks
    )
  return
    IF(
      ISFILTERED('Calendar'[weekNumWeekCommence]) || ISFILTERED('Calendar'[Calendar Financial Year]),
      result
    )
```

We are getting all in scope `YOY Year & Week` values, then `REMOVEFILTERS` on the `Calendar` so we get all rows, then filtering on `Year & Week` based on `YOY Year & Week`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but that seems to give the same result

Comment: Try the above now, you want to exclude 0's it seems.

Comment: also returns the same result - I tried something similar before trying to disregard the 0 but it still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Not according to looking at it, at the week level (not day level): https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUgX4.png

Comment: I tweaked the code to take the day into account which now gets the average for the days within that week and it works, thanks